# Which identifier variable is better to pass as an argument to a method?

Tags: c#, variables, properties, argument-passing

Suppose the following method:

```
public void ShareClassStuff(int shareClassId)
{
    var shareClass = _shareClassService.GetShareClassById(shareClassId);

    (if shareClass != null)
        var shareClassStat = _shareClassService.GetShareClassStat(shareClass.Id);

    //go on to do stuff with shareClass & shareClassStat 
}
```

Here, I get a `shareClass` by passing shareClassId to a service which returns the object I need. Next, I have to pass an Id to another method to get some different data.

The question I have is whether in the second service call, it's better to use the `shareClassId` variable, e.g.

```
GetShareClassStat(shareClassId)
```

or the `Id` property of the shareClass object, e.g.

```
GetShareClassStat(shareClass.Id)
```

or does it even matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it matters from a performance perspective, however, I would pass shareClassId to the second method, and not shareClass.Id.

The reason is when you use shareClass.Id, you now have a dependency on the positioning of the code.  _shareClassService.GetShareClassById must be called first before _shareClassService.GetShareClassStat.  Also, you introduce a dependency on the implementation of _shareClassService.GetShareClassById to properly populate the Id property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters much.

Answer (score 0):

While one could probably argue both ways, there is a very tiny benefit to passing `shareClassId`:

`shareClass.Id` is a property, therefore a method call (which may or may not be inlined by optimization). `shareClassId` is a simple integer.

So there is a very small advantage to passing the parameter.

**Updated**

There's another reason one might prefer to use the parameter: It's consistant. You used the parameter for the first "lookup by ID", so use the parameter again the second time.

Neither of these reasons are terribly compelling, but since you asked, I assume that you are interested in any imaginable reasoning.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that if `shareClass` itself is passed, the property would still need to be evaluated within the called method.

Comment: @Jon: The question is: Should I pass the ID I already have and know to be the same value as the Id property of the object I used the ID to retreive, or should I turn around and use the property? It is clear that the `GetShareClassStat` method is just another lookup method that returns an object from an Id. While you're answer is useful, it doesn't seem to apply to this scenario.

Comment: I think we'd need to know more to say for sure. I'd say that if you're right, my answer *is* useful and should lead the OP to just pass in the ID - because that's all it should logically depend on.

Comment: @Jon: but then the OP will be left with the same question: how should I pass just the ID? `localVariableWithTheId` or `someObject.TheIdFromTheProperty`?

Comment: @Martinho: Ah. It's quite possible that I've misunderstood the question completely. Oops. I thought the question was about whether the method should take just an ID, or a reference to the whole object. Will delete my entirely-incorrect answer...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't matter. It would only matter later on if for some reason your GetShareClassById() method stopped returning nulls and instead started returning an empty class. Now you have a class with an invalid id. Not that it would ever happen, just saying that it would cause issues.

If you care about gaining 0.0001 seconds in speed then pass the variable.